# Laravel Livewire Echo matchmaking

Tags: php, laravel, echo, pusher, laravel-livewire

I am trying to create a match making system. When a match is found, I want to broadcast to the user the match was found for. I can't figure this out - should I use polling instead?

My User model has a belongsToMany relationship with a Match model.

Heres my code that does not work.

Route:

```
Broadcast::channel('match.{matchId}', function ($user, $matchId) {
    return $user->matches()->contains('id', $matchId);
});
```

Component:

```
class PlayComponent extends Component
{
    public $matchId;

    public function getListeners()
    {
        return [
            "echo-private:match.{$this->matchId},JoinMatch" => 'joinMatch',
        ];
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.play-component', [
            'matches' => Auth::user()->matches()->get()->toArray(),
        ]);
    }

    public function play()
    {
        if ($match = Match::where('status', 'waiting')->first()) {
            $this->matchId = $match->id;
            event(new JoinMatch($match));
        }
        else {
            $this->matchId = Auth::user()->matches()->create(['status' => 'waiting']);
        }
    }

    public function joinMatch()
    {
        // ???
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" wire:click="play">Play</button>
    <hr>
    <pre>{{ print_r($matches, true) }}</pre>
</div>
```

Event:

```
class JoinMatch implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $match;

    public function __construct(Match $match)
    {
        $this->match = $match;
        $this->match->users()->attach(Auth::user()->id);
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('match.' . $this->match->id);
    }
}
```

How do I make this work? I think the problem is `getListeners` expects a parameter, but this parameter may not exist for the matched user yet.

Comment: You mention it isn't working, but what is the error you receive? 
What about it isn't working?